# how to convert int to string to get parameter?

Tags: java

In MY SQL table my first column is id which is int so how i can get parameter. How can i convert into string from int. I am using SQLyog ultimate where i want to create auto increment to id column so do i need to add here.

```
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
    String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String landlinenumber = request.getParameter("landlinenumber");
    String mobilenumber = request.getParameter("mobilenumber");
    String emailid = request.getParameter("emailid");
    String standardyear = request.getParameter("standardyear");
    String schoolcollage = request.getParameter("schoolcollage");
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String projects = request.getParameter("projects");
    String skills = request.getParameter("skills");
```

Comment: but if it is auto increment then still we need to write as u said??

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Integer.valueOf()` to convert a String to an Integer.

```
Integer id  = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt()`.

Example:

```
Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
```

Just make sure that in the parameter you don't have any invalid character for a Integer, otherwise you will get `NumberFormatException`.

Also, usually when you have a column `id` in your DB it's already declared as `int`. In this case you don't need to use the `Parse`, just store the value inside an `Integer` variable.